# Generating direct invite link for Beta testing in Testflight

Tags: ios, testing, testflight

I have an app which I have on testflight but I want to allow people to register and receive a beta invite unique to that registration so I do not have a public link

is there any software or any API's that exist already in the wild that can help me achieve this?

Thanks in advance.